# Does highcharts store my data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am making graphs with Highcharts for internal audience at my organization. It is important for my audience that data I use to make Highchart graphs do not get shared, relayed, or stored outside of the intranet.

1. Do JavaScript graph libraries store data when library users create graphs through them? Even briefly?
2. Does Highcharts store my data when I create graphs using their library? I could not find the answer to my question in their conditions of use.

Comment: No. It is an open source lib, and just creates graphs within the client. No data is sent outside of the browser.

Comment: One aspect that you need to think of is if you export the chart and do not have your own export server set up - it defaults to sending chart object to export.highcharts.com to render the image/PDF. You can bypass this by having your own export server or using client-side exporting.